# How to learn Strichartz estimates for wave equations?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, hyperbolic-pde, wave-equation

I am a student planning to learn some knowledge about Strichartz estimates for wave equations. My goal is to understand the Strichartz estimates or a priori estiamtes of weak solutions for the linear wave equation as follows
\begin{eqnarray}
\partial_t^2u-\operatorname{div}(A(x)\nabla u)=0,
\end{eqnarray}
where $ A(x)=(a_{ij}(x)):\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}^{d\times d} $ is a symmetric real matrix such that $ a_{ij}(x)\xi_i\xi_j\geq\lambda|\xi|^2 $ for all $ x\in\mathbb{R}^d $ and $ \xi\in\mathbb{R}^d $. So what should I start? I know that Sogge wrote some book about it and there may be some other books or papers abou the topic. What I want to ask is that what order should I follow? Now I have some basic knowledge about linear wave equations(mainly from "Evans pde") and harmonic analysis(mainly from "Stein harmonic analysis").